# Splitting members of series using regular expressions with strings

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas

I asked a similar question about a week ago, and tried to mess with that code to suit a different purpose, but couldn't seem to make it work.

I want to split a string using month abbreviations as the delimiters (so, I'd have JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUNE, etc)

I tried using

```
df['a'] = [re.split(r'[JUNE|JULY]+', x) for x in df['a']
```

as well as some variations on that (adding `.group(0)` before `for x` )

I'm guessing my problem is syntax with the delimiters. Looking at the documentation for regular expressions, I should be able to use strings as delimiters, but can only find a way to do it using `re.search`.

Have also tried

```
df['a'] = [re.split[(('JUNE', 'JULY'), x).group(0) for x in df['a']]
```

the data in the series is something like this:

```
df['a'] = ['ABCJUNE123', 'DEFJULY456', 'DEGJUNE765', 'DEFJUNE345']
```

and I want:

```
df['a'] = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'DEG', 'DEF']
```

What am I missing from my expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
r'JUNE|JULY'
```

Example:

```
>>> re.split(r'JUNE|JULY', 'ABCJUNE123')
['ABC', '123']
```

`[JUNE|JULY]+` regex doesn't represent `JUNE` or `JULY`.

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks! Searching the documentation that was right near the top, I'll look more closely next time. I was using `group` to only get the first member (which didn't work), but then I realized it was a list.